# If $G,H$ are monoids and not groups, prove that $f(e_G)=e_H$ may be wrong.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

**Problem:** If $f:G\longrightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups, then $f(e_G)=e_H$ and $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}, \forall a\in G$. Show by example that the first conclusion may be false if $G, H$ are monoids that are not groups.

**Solution:** By contrary, let $\forall a\in G; f(e_G)=e_H$. But we have $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$, so $f(a)f(a^{-1})=f(a)f(a)^{-1}\Longrightarrow f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a)^{-1}$, therefore $e_G=aa^{-1}$ and $e_H=f(a)f(a)^{-1}$ which is in contradiction with the assumption which says $G$ and $H$ are not groups.

I think my proof is a little shaky or maybe wrong. What is your solution?

Comment: the argument you give does not make sense. Why won't you give an example of monoids $G,H$ and a function $f:G\to H$ which preserves the operation, but not the units?

Comment: I think this is a wrong claim!

Comment: @IttayWeiss Do you think $\mathbb{Z}_4^*$ is a monoid and not a group?

Comment: it is a group. Why?

Comment: @IttayWeiss What is the inverse element of $2\in\mathbb{Z}_4^*$

Comment: $2$ is not an element in $\mathbb Z^*_4$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually we impose $f(e_G)=e_H$ as part of the definition of a monoid homomorphism, but for the purposes of this exercise let's assume instead a semigroup homomorphism only.

Your argument assumes the second part of the original propsition *does* hold true even if $G,H$ are not groups (you used $f(a)f(a)^{-1}=e_H$), but you cannot assume that.

The idea is that the image $f(G)\subset H$ should have a "local identity" which acts as an identity on the image $f(G)$ but not on the whole of $H$. An easy way to accomplish this: let $h\in H$ be idempotent (that is, $h^2=h$) but not $e_H$, and let $f(g)=h$ be a constant function.

Comment: +1 For example, the element $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4^*$ would work.

Comment: @NotNotLogical But $0\notin \mathbb{Z}_4^*$ Do you mean the element $1\in \mathbb{Z}_4^*$?

Comment: @Milad I guess I was referring to the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with multiplication modulo $4$.

Answer (score 3):

The example given below shows that if $G $ , $H$ both are monoids then  the conclusion be false.

A ring with $1$ is a monoid under multiplication, and ring homomorphisms do not have to send $1$ to $1$ (unless explicitly defined to do so). One example is the following:
$$M=(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z,\cdot)\\(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$$together with the function $$h:M\to M\\(a,b)\mapsto (a,0)$$ This function clearly satisfies the homomorphism property, but it doesn't send $e_M=(1,1)$ to $(1,1)$.